# How to implemet special horizontall scrollview UI in android

Tags: android, user-interface

Yesterday, i saw that an Android TV that uses below mechanism to show android recent app feature:
[image]

I try to using the HorizontalScrollView or horizontal list view to implement this, but failed.
Dose anyone konw how to implement above features?

Comment: show some. What you have tried yet and failed??

Comment: hi @pskink, i got 2 problems: 1 dose the HorizontalScrollView has the "focus"? if yes, how can i fix this focus to the center of the screen?2 once we launch this app, the let the right side of horizontalscrollview must be at the center of the screen(just like above 1st figure), and if user press left/right key, it will move like above the 2nd figure.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: @pskink, by my known, google no longer use this ui component that is replaced by the HorizontalScrollview now.

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan, do you have any advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using leanback:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/package-summary.html

By default it is used to build very "standard" looking applications.

What you need is RowsFragment, and setAdapter method.
It takes adapter of RowList which has adapter of items (your objects) and use custom Presenter to display you data.

Check this sample for implementation details:
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback